# ASP.NET web service throw System.Net.WebException when upload file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a a web service in asp.net which need to upload files to another server. The code run well when I play under Debug mode in Visual Studio. But when I host in IIS and call it, it throw System.Net.WebException. Here is my code:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string UploadFileToServer(string m_fileName, string m_username, string m_url)
    {
        string m_localFilePath = _currentDirectory + "\\" + m_username + "\\" + m_fileName;
        FileStream m_localFileStream = File.Open(m_localFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        var reader = new BinaryReader(m_localFileStream);

        byte[] m_rawBytes = new byte[m_localFileStream.Length];
        reader.Read(m_rawBytes, 0, m_rawBytes.Length);
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(m_url);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.KeepAlive = false;

            Stream m_requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            m_requestStream.Write(m_rawBytes, 0, m_rawBytes.Length);
            m_requestStream.Close();
            m_localFileStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse m_response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader m_reader = new StreamReader(m_response.GetResponseStream());

            string s = m_reader.ReadToEnd();

            return s;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString() + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

It is very frustrated for me and it's not possible to turn it on my Visual Studio all the time.  Any suggestion or solutions? Thanks.

Comment: What is the message and stacktrace of the WebException ?

Comment: When you "play under debug mode in visual studio", do you have everything (the file you want to upload, the webservice you are calling) on your local machine? Could it be that when you deploy your webservice and run it you are trying to open a file that does not exist in the specified directory?